# SoX on Windows 7 64-Bit Outfile Missing

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, troubleshooting, sox

I have come across the strangest problem when trying to run sox.exe on my Windows 7 installation. Whenever I try and record audio it works without any issues but it will not output an audio file. The crazy thing is that when I use the play command it successfully plays what I just recorded. Has anyone ever heard of this happening?

Here are the commands (and output) that I'm using:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Vox\sox-14-4-0>sox -d test.wav trim 0 00:05

Input File     : 'default' (waveaudio)
Channels       : 2
Sample Rate    : 48000
Precision      : 16-bit
Sample Encoding: 16-bit Signed Integer PCM

In:0.00% 00:00:05.03 [00:00:00.00] Out:240k  [      |      ]        Clip:0
Done.

C:\Program Files (x86)\Vox\sox-14-4-0>play test.wav

test.wav:

 File Size: 960k      Bit Rate: 1.54M
  Encoding: Signed PCM
  Channels: 2 @ 16-bit
Samplerate: 48000Hz
Replaygain: off
  Duration: 00:00:05.00

In:100%  00:00:05.00 [00:00:00.00] Out:240k  [      |      ]        Clip:0
Done.
```

Am I losing my mind or is something up here?

Comment: What's the question again? `play test.wav` sees the file, what program fails to see it?

Comment: The question is why does the program not output an audio file? I can play back the filename that I just recorded by using the play command, but if I browse to that folder with windows explorer or the command prompt there is no audio file listed. I know, it's very strange.

Comment: If `play` can see so should any other program, unless some odd setting is enabled.

Comment: Well I was able to get it working by uninstalling sox-14-4-0 and installing 14.3.2. Now the program works normally. I understand that if the program can read the file then I should be able to locate it on the file system but that was not the case. For some reason the program would play back but if I tried to browse to the location it wasn't there. Perhaps I'm overlooking something obvious though.

Comment: Run command prompt to that directory and type attrib. Attribute will show you what attributes the file is. Seems odd, but it may not show up in Explorer if the file has a hidden attribute and you Explorer, Tools, Options are set to hide files with the hidden attribute on.